# Enable a single .ts file ( mp2t transport stream ) playback within Chromium : mac platform

Tags: macos, chromium, chromium-embedded, mpeg2-ts

We are experimenting with a **Chromium based application ( using cef ) to playback a single .TS file** with H.264 codec and aac audio - **for mac platform.**

We would like to specify the **video/mp2t mime type** in the video tag to playback the file - currently the playback does-not begin.

**Here is what we already tried, however have not been successful :**

1. Tried enabling the ts-parser  by setting the "enable_mse_mpeg2ts_stream_parser=true" flag in the Chromium + cef build process,
2. Tried adding {"video/mp2t", "ts"} pair to MimeInfo "kPrimaryMappings" in mime_util.cc

**Additional Observations:**

- we were able to playback a .mp4 file  containing h.264 codec ( enabled "proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome" to get this working )
- Also we found that google-chrome browser doesnot playback a .ts file and instead triggers a download of it : this is what we would like to change in our chromium/cef based application where we would like to playback the .ts file.

**we are fairly new to chromium codebase and we would like to get your suggestions w.r.t settings / code to help achieve this.**

Regards,

Arjun

Comment: Chrome does not support that container type. There is nothing you can do server side other than converting to (f)mp4.

Comment: @szatmary, this question is not about the Chrome browser, it is about the "chromium" open-source project.

Comment: My comment still applies.

Comment: @szatmary, Could you please elaborate, why you think it cannot be achieved by modifying the chromium codebase ?